# How to Format Today's date as mm-dd-yyyy in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath, date

I have a 2010 InfoPath form with 2 controls. I have a dropdown control called Colors with values Red, Yellow and Green. Lastly I have TextBox control called TaskComplete below:

[image]

I then created an Action for my Colors control. The condition is if Colors = Red then set the value in TaskComplete to Today’s date below:

[image]

However, when I set the colors to Red, it returns the date as yyyy-mm-dd shown below:

[image]

How can I have Today’s date return in mm-dd-yyyy format?

Comment: Thank you. saved me time this morning looking for this very answer on how to format a date field that has a formula using now() instead of today(). YAY

Comment: As Aspire27 said, use now(). That's pretty idiotic, Microsoft. I had tried having my Date field look at the other pull-down field for when it changed. That didn't work. I had told the date field to format as YYYY-MM-DD (which is how it appeared in the date text box and was acceptable when hand-typed). No go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Data type to Date and reformatted the rule to use now() instead of Today(). That returned the date as mm-dd-yyyy format.

Answer (score 3):

When you set the field type, did you format that date block as the appropriate setting?

[image]

Comment: You're wanting me to change my 'Data type' in Properties of my TextBox to Date? Reason I ask because, as is, the Format button is grayed out. However, if I change it to Date I can change the Format.

Comment: The easiest way is to change the field from text to date and then add whatever function you need.

Comment: I opened the properties of my TextBox and set the Data type to 'Date'. I then click on Format and choose the format as mm/dd/yyyy. I then test and when I change the Colors to Red, the TextBox border goes red dashes and the error states 'Only date or date time allowed'.

Comment: You may have to go back and review the rule that you placed and or update the rule to show the new "date field".

Comment: The rule is pretty simple. If Color =  Red set TaskComplete to Today(). No error in that rule. It has to be done another way maybe in Properties but no clue as to how else I can format.

Comment: I just did this and it worked for me.  When you typed the formula for "today()" did you type it =today()

Comment: I just used the function called 'today()'. Are you using a Date control? I ask because I was using TextBox control to display the date.

Answer (score 0):

As said...use now() function.

Infopath suggest you use it for SharePoint list columns when today() is selected.

[image]